# Cant access domain root directory, only www?

Tags: dns, subdomain

so i have a simple apache2 setup, basically installed it and then uploaded my HTML files to /var/www/html

i dont think that is the problem anyhow

basically im messing around with domains and the issue is i can only access it via www.cyanxsaber.com when its setup like so http://puu.sh/npAIw.png

BUT if i add

```
CNAME * cyanxsaber.com.
```

then any URL connects to it (eg. poopy.cyanxsaber.com) but this does let the plain cyanxsaber.com work

is there a way to set it up so only www. and just plain cyanxsaber.com works?

edit: yeah i know the domain is cringy :P i just wanted one to muck around with XD im still trying to think of a serious one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update your apache configuration to listen for each domain.
Try adding a ServerAlias directive which tells apache explicitly which directory to point to when it sees the domain.

```
ServerAlias cyanxsaber.com
```